# Disable SSL revoked use certifiate from accessing nginx

Tags: nginx, ssl, https

We have nginx with a https self-signed certificate that allows access only if you have a certificate signed by the server certificate. We use this internally for a build machine.

Question is: Is it possible to revoke a user certificate that was issued by the same CA repository and signed with the CA self-signed certificate and in this way prevent the user of this certificate from accessing the server?

I have tried

```
$ openssl ca -config openssl.cnf -revoke newcerts/XXXXXXXXXXXX.pem
```

which revokes the certificate but the user is still able to access the server.
Thanks.

Comment: It is not enough to revoke a certificate but this revocation must be published (for example inside a CRL - certificate revocation list) and the revocation must also be explicitly checked against the latest list - see `ssl_crl` in nginx documentation.

Comment: Thanks. Yes the ssl_crl was the option that I was missing